# Python unittest issue

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a unittest script in a 'tests' directory which I execute like:
$ python3 -m unittest mainmodule.tests,

the entire class is a super simple one, has an assertEquals(1, 1), the script runs,
but it says: 0 tests ran in 0.000 seconds .... OK.

No matter how I run the script (from console or via itnerpreter etc).

I'm using python 3.1.2

Ideas?

Edit: the method starts with 'test'.

Comment: Could you please add your code to the question? (If you don't want to share it, create a very simple version that reproduces the problem)

Comment: Without code, this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your package structure should be something like this:

```
$ tree mainmodule
mainmodule/
|--__init__.py
|--file1.py
|--file2.py
|--tests
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--test_file1.py
```

In which case you should run:

```
$ python3 -m unittest mainmodule.tests.test_file1
```

or simply:

```
$ python3 -m unittest
```

and see what output comes out.

**Note:**
If you're not using relative imports in your test file, you can always add at the end of it something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and then run `$ python3 test_file1.py` to test your code.

See the [unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.2/library/unittest.html) for examples.

Comment: if this was your case or it help solving your problem you'll may consider to accept this anwser?